# Can't use umlauts (äöü) in any editor over ssh

Tags: ssh, putty, nano

If I write Umlauts (äöü) in putty, then weird things happen. It seems like it worked but as soon as I go over with the cursor then it goes like this:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

And if I go very often from left to right then this is the result:

[image: 4]

Is this a known bug? How to make it work?

Comment: Why are there so many close votes and downvotes? How should I learn what I did wrong if no one says something?!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, explain. I programmed something over ssh, stackoverflow is related to programming right?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, you can programm with any editor and there are plenty editors available in linux e.g. nano and vi

Comment: Then stackoverflow should show a message saying that this question is off-topic as soon if someone tries to add off-topic tags to the post and prevent to ask the question or redirect to the right subforum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to go into putty settings and set encoding to UTF-8
Settings -> Window -> Translation
[image]

Comment: Thx for the hint, it is already set to UTF-8

Comment: if you type `locale` in console then it should also say `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` or something with UTF-8. if not then you could try matching putty settings to this.

Comment: Thx for your hint, it just says `LANG=`

Comment: you could try `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and see if it fixes the issue. `locale -a` to see what is available. There may be many causes and too many solutions how to fix, this may help: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale Good luck.

Comment: Thx! Your last comment was solving my issue :) I don't know why someone downvoted us.